# How to copy page from one PDF document to another and add margin

Tags: java, itext, itext7

Can someone please give me example of copying pages with iText 7 from one PDF to another.

I need to copy page from one PDF to another and leave some space on the top for the barcode ... but every time I copy page with:

```
srcDoc.copyPagesTo(Integer.valueOf(tBrStr), Integer.valueOf(tBrStr), pdf)
```

The copied page fits over whole page and I cannot put margin on the top of page for barcode.

Comment: Isn't that explained in the iText 7 jump-start tutorial? See [chapter 5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document) and look for the example that generates the PDF shown in figure 5.6.

Comment: for(int i = 1; i < srcDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {     
{     
         srcDoc.copyPagesTo(i, i, pdf);
}

Comment: Problem is that copied page in new document is over whole page and I cannot make region for barcode which I generate with event on page end. I first copy this pages to new document and add barcode to top of the document. I cannot find the way to set margin to copied page and to have isolated place for barcode.

Comment: I used your example but I have same behaviour ... I get text over copied page and there is no top margin placed.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I can't answer questions I don't understand.

Comment: I have 2 PDF files: one is stored to database and second I need to generate from selected pages of first one. I need to copy selected pages from first PDF and insert them into new generated PDF with barcode on top. I used method copyPagesTo but I can't set top margin on new generated PDF to put barcode on it ... every copied page with copyPagesTo method is 100% over page ... I need some way separate copied page from the barcode which should be on top without overlapping content of copied page and barcode ...

Comment: Are you aware that you need to change the page size (the `/MediaBox` and possibly the `/CropBox`) to achieve this, and that content in a PDF can't reflow? For instance: if your original PDF has A4 pages, the new PDF will have pages that are bigger than A4. Are you aware that this is inherent to the PDF format?

Comment: My original PDF is A4 format and generated is also A4 format ... I use copyPagesTo() method to copy pages from original to generated PDF .. copy operation goes well and I get pages copied to generated PDF, but I can't move copied page in generated PDF from the top ... I tried to set margin top to document before copying pages ... I use on start page event to generate barcode and I get barcode + page overlapping ... I need some solution to move copied page for example 80px from the top or to scale it to leave place for barcode which goes on top without content overlapping

Comment: No, if you want to add an extra margin, your page size needs to increase to a size greater than A4. If that doesn't happen, you are doing something wrong. If you don't want the page size to increase, then your requirement can't be met. I have no idea what you mean when you write *I tried to set margin top to document before copying pages ... I use on start page event to generate barcode and I get barcode + page overlapping.* All of that sounds very strange to me. As I said before: I can't answer questions I don't understand.

Comment: Can I re-scale copied page to be smaller than in original?

Comment: Yes, that's also explained in the tutorial, but be aware that you can run into problems with interactive content when you do this.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed :))